# What should do if question asker does not respond to correct answer and comment?

Tags: discussion

In StackOverFlow, sometimes question asker obviously uses comment idea, or answer solution but without giving resonse to the comment and the answer, is that responsible manner? what should we do for those kind of question asker?

Comment: What do you mean by “obviously uses comment idea, or answer solution“? Does it become obvious in another question?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft He means "found the solution presented in a comment or answer helpful and made use of it" then scrammed without providing feedback (upvote, acceptance, or comments).

Comment: I suppose I have gaven correct answer or comment, but question asker did not and never respond anything.

Comment: @Dan Bron is right understanding

Comment: I think those kind of question asker is not responble for the question, because other solution seekers could have similar issue.

Comment: @Xingchen That's just the reality of it. Many users are one-shot "help vampires"; the best advice we can give is accept it, shrug, and move on. Don't sweat it. If it really bothers you, learn to recognize the hallmarks of vampire questions or users and avoid them. Many of us do.

Comment: @DanBron: I was rather talking about why it becomes obvious that the user uses the solution. If the user just scrammed, this would be difficult to find out and the classical problem you described. If the asker did indeed in some way reveal that he uses an answer (e.g., by posting another question in which he uses it), this is a slightly different story.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Of course I don't know in OP's case, but in my experience it's obvious the asker "used" your solution because the answer itself was obvious (i.e. the question was trivial, or at least trivial to google, and the asker was a help vampire).

Comment: I agree with your discussion. And I think after question asker submits a question, then the question becomes to be a public issue, so asker has responsible to tell others if the answers and comments to the question are correct/useful or not.

Comment: @Xingchen You may believe the the asker responsible, but there is literally no way to hold him accountable. And a law which cannot be enforced is not a law. As I said, your best course of action here is: accept that this is the reality of the situation. It will not change. There is no way to make it change. So you can either take it in stride (ie not care; after all, your answer/comment will be there for the next guy to see, whether it's been recognized by the OP or not), or avoid the types of questions/users that are likely to respond this way, or give up on SE altogether. That's all.